# Change Label from outside the class it was declared in

Tags: java, label, awt

I am wondering if it is possible to change the text of a label (from the awt library) from outside of the class it was declared in? e.g have class that declares and intialises the gui but different class that processes information that will be displayed in the label.

Comment: please if isn't there really important reason, then don't use Java Component from last millenium

Comment: Have to use awt, would have much prefered to use swing.

Comment: WTF is education today about? Obliging people to use deprecated methods and libraries!? This should be a sign for you to be very critical to the prof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. **Recommended**: Create a setter for the label text:

   ```
   public void setLabelText(String txt)
   {
        label.setText(txt);
   }
   ```

   And then use it like this:

   ```
   yourObject.setLabelText("Sent from another class");
   ```
2. Make your label `public`. This way you can access it from every class of your application:

   ```
   public Label myLabel;
   ```

   Now, you can access it from another class like this:

   ```
   myObject.myLabel.setText("Sent from another class");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many ways to access a label outside the class it was declared.

1. You can change the access modifier of label from private to public (which is not recommended at all).
2. You can use setter and getter methods for accessing a variable outside scope of the class, which it is declared in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can always declare the labels and other fields in a properties files, it will help you to localize your app better. Cheers!